# use of < var < in embedded if statements

Tags: python

I'm learning Python via Udemy and we did a coding project where you have to get a user's height and weight, calculate their BMI and print the result. In my code, for the embedded `if` (`elif`) statements, I did something like this (variable is bmi to hold the actual BMI calculation): `elif 18.5 < bmi < 25`

```py
if bmi < 18.5:
  print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}, you are slightly underweight.")
elif 18.5 < bmi < 25:
  print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}, you have a normal weight.")
elif 25 < bmi < 30:
  print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}, you are slightly overweight.")
```

Now, the instructor instead did this: `elif bmi < 25`.
She didn't use the format `< var <` like I did. Now my code worked just fine from what I can tell but it was implied that there could be a potential issue using my format. Can anyone confirm/deny that my format could cause a problem under the right circumstances???

I just want to make sure I'm coding correctly.

Answer (score 4):

> now, the instructor instead did this: elif bmi < 25

This is better for two reasons:

1. You already know bmi >= 18.5 because if it were lower you would have entered the first if clause and not reached this elif test. So it's a waste of effort to test again whether for `bmi > 18.5`
2. If bmi is exactly equal to 18.5, none of your tests will match and your code will probably do something unexpected. You should be testing for `bmi >= 18.5` (which again is redundant because of point 1), or including an elif clause specifically to check `bmi == 18.5` if that case needs special handling.

Answer (score -1):

`x < bmi < y` is perfectly fine Python code. Python will interpret it as `x < bmi and bmi < y`:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/

However, as @The Photon said, your code will have a bug if you input `bmi = 18.5` or `25`.

Since `if, elif, ...` statements are evaluated in sequence, it's better to avoid introducing bugs, and work as your intructor did (`if bmi < 25, etc.`), because you already know that this line of code will only execute after the previous `if/elif` expressions failed (like `if bmi < 18.5`).